# How to detect macOS laptop is sleeping in Java

Tags: java, macos

Problem:
Running Java client on a Mac Laptop, When the Mac goes into sleep mode (for example when the lid is closed), my client "pingServer" thread successfully sends a ping request packet to the server (I see the ping request packet in the server), however when the lid is closed, we do not receive a response. (Understandably)

I want to detect that the MacBook Pro laptop is going to sleep or is sleeping, so I can interrupt the ping thread until the Mac is no longer sleeping.

I have seen a "SystemSleepListener" in the Desktop class, but I have not found any code examples of implementation.

How can I detect macOS sleep mode in Java?

Answer (score 4):

This should be possible without using classes only available in Apple Java:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;

Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
SystemSleepListener systemSleepListener = new SystemSleepListener() {

    @Override
    public void systemAboutToSleep(SystemSleepEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Going to sleep");
    }

    @Override
    public void systemAwoke(SystemSleepEvent e) {

    }

};
desktop.addAppEventListener(systemSleepListener);
```

Note that some platforms do not support `SystemSleepListener`. You can check if it is supported by calling

```
desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.APP_EVENT_SYSTEM_SLEEP)
```